# How to plot two variables over the top of each other using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
Engine | Predicted RUL| Actual RUL 
1      | 172          | 112      
2      | 126          | 98
3      | 27           | 69
4      | 52           | 82
5      | 84           | 91
...    | ...          | ...
100    | 5            | 20
```

I would like to visualize Predicted RUL compared to Actual RUL for each Engine. Similar to [this](https://i0.wp.com/4cda.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/result-no-mods.png?resize=768%2C257&ssl=1).

I am able to make a simple bar plot using only one of the variables, but I don't know how to add the second over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the data in long format and use `geom_col` to generate the plot.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Engine, names_to = "RUL_Type") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Engine, value, fill = RUL_Type)) + 
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha=.3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Perhaps, using dodged bar plot would be easier to visualize ?

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Engine, names_to = "RUL_Type") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Engine, value, fill = RUL_Type)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Engine = 1:5, Predicted_RUL = c(172L, 126L, 27L, 
52L, 84L), Actual_RUL = c(112L, 98L, 69L, 82L, 91L)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I agree, dodged bar plot does look better. Though I have 100 engines so it looked a little crowded, I just adjusted the width and it looks much better. Thanks again.